# SwapChainBackgroundPanel not calling Rendering event when GPU picking - DirectX and XAML

Tags: xaml, directx, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, directx-11

I have already sort of asked this question already here ([Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788021/compositiontarget-rendering-not-being-called-when-onpointermoved-event)) but it only got a handful of views and zero answers/comments so I thought I'd give it a go again with some more info that I've found.

I basically have a Windows Store DirectX + XAML app that I'm developing. I currently have the problem that the Rendering event of the **SwapChainBackgroundPanel** that I use for DirectX rendering (as per the Windows 8 example on MSDN) sometimes isn't called when the user is interacting with the app.

It will continue to update if I am doing something with the camera such as changing what it's looking at based on touch/mouse position but it won't be called if I am picking and I don't know why.

I use the standard GPU picking method (where I render the scene with a unique color for each object and then take a 1x1 texture of the press area to find the selected object) but when I am using this picking technique to select multiple objects (the user drags their finger/mouse over many objects) Rendering isn't being called. So in effect what happens is, lots of objects get selected but the user only sees this when they remove their finger/stop pressing the mouse button.

Is there any reason why this is happening? Is it because of the GPU picking method? And if so is there a way around it rather than using the ray-trace picking method (which considerably slows down picking for a large number of objects)?

Has anyone else had this problem? Is there an explanation from Microsoft anywhere that it is deliberate that rendering doesn't get called while this is happening?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: How often are you rendering this texture? My guess is that if you are rendering it for each mouse/pointer movement, then it could considerably slow you down. You should maybe try to profile it.

If that is the problem, perhaps you can render it asynchronously?

Comment: I don't do it every mouse pointer, I do a movement test to slow that down but yeah it is probably quite a lot. Is there anyway to do what I want to do though? Other than doing it asynchronously I guess - but will that even speed it up?

Comment: How do you render that 1x1 texture? Are you sending the whole scene again?

Another way to do it might be accessing the backbuffer directly. You could try to copy its contents to a CPU-readable texture via `CopyResource` or `LoadTextureFromTexture`. Then you can compute the data position of the coordinates you want to read pixel values from.

You should consider doing this check asynchronously. If it is a lengthy operation then it will block the UI thread if it is executed there. You can try a `BackgroundWorker` or the new `Task` api as you should be targeting .net4.5.